# Reading a single-entry ZIP file incrementally from an unseekable stream in Python

Tags: python, zip

We often need to unzip extremely large (unencrypted) ZIP files that are hosted by partners over HTTPS. Generally, the ZIP file format (shown below) needs to download in full to be able to see the "central directory" data to identify file entries; however, in our case, we can assume there's exactly one large text file that was zipped, and we could begin extracting and parsing data immediately without needing to wait for the ZIP file to buffer.

If we were using C#, we could use https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Unpack-a-zip-using-ZipInputStream [(implementation here)](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/8f7d89201afa13c814f9b3d1813884ffe0ec7025/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Zip/ZipInputStream.cs) which handles this pattern elegantly.

However, it seems that the Python standard library's `zipfile` module doesn't support this type of streaming; it assumes that the input file-like object is seekable, and all tutorials point to iterating first over `namelist()` which seeks to the central directory data, then `open(name)` which seeks back to the file entry.

Many other examples on StackOverflow recommend using `BytesIO(response.content)` which might appear to pipe the content in a streaming way; however, .content in the Requests library consumes the entire stream and buffers the entire thing to memory.

Is there an alternate way to use `zipfile` or a third-party Python library to do this in a completely streaming way?

[image: ZIP file format]

Comment: Generally speaking what you want to do is impossible. However, for the special case of a zip file composed of exactly one file, you could start from the beginning of the file, read first file (and only) entry manually, and then unzip the following data yourself (with `zlib`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an alternate way to use zipfile or a third-party Python library to do this in a completely streaming way?

Yes: https://github.com/uktrade/stream-unzip can do it [full disclosure: essentially written by me].

> We often need to unzip extremely large (unencrypted) ZIP files that are hosted by partners over HTTPS.

The example from the README shows how to to this, using `stream-unzip` and `httpx`

```py
from stream_unzip import stream_unzip
import httpx

def zipped_chunks():
    # Any iterable that yields a zip file
    with httpx.stream('GET', 'https://www.example.com/my.zip') as r:
        yield from r.iter_bytes()

for file_name, file_size, unzipped_chunks in stream_unzip(zipped_chunks()):
    for chunk in unzipped_chunks:
        print(chunk)
```

If you do just want the first file, you can use `break` after the first file:

```
for file_name, file_size, unzipped_chunks in stream_unzip(zipped_chunks()):
    for chunk in unzipped_chunks:
        print(chunk)
    break
```

Also

> Generally, the ZIP file format (shown below) needs to download in full to be able to see the "central directory" data to identify file entries

This isn't completely true.

Each file has a "local" header that contains its name, and it can be worked out when the compressed data for any member file ends (via information in the local header if it's there or from the compressed data itself). While there is more information in the central file directory at the end, if you just need the name + bytes of the files, then it *is* possible to start unzipping a ZIP file, that contains multiple files, as it's downloading.

I can't claim its absolutely possible in all cases: technically ZIP allows for many different compression algorithms and I haven't investigated them all. However, for DEFLATE, which is the one most commonly used, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's even possible to download one specific file from .zip without downloading whole file. All you need is server that allows to read bytes in ranges, fetch end recored (to know size of CD), fetch central directory (to know where file starts and ends) and then fetch proper bytes and handle them.

Using [Onlinezip](https://github.com/kgonia/onlinezip) you can handle file like local file. Event API is identical as FileZip in python

[full disclosure: I'm author of library]